# Is there a way to reserve a pipeline for an agent pool in TFS or VSTS?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have started running automated UI tests in Releases. We are allowing our QA to kick off these tests manually in the test hub so it is very easy for them to use up all of the available pipelines.

I want to be able to ensure there is always one pipeine available for builds. Is there a way to reserve a pipeline for builds or is there a way to tell a release to use a specific pipeline?

Also, we will soon be switching to VSTS. So I ask the same question for VSTS also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "reserve a pipeline" you mean "reserve an agent", then yes. You can create a separate agent and separate agent queue, and only your test automation release definitions will be assigned that agent queue.

Another option is to use a custom Capability on the agent and a custom Demand on the release definition to restrict the release definition to only run on a specific agent.

You can't "reserve a pipeline" if you're talking about concurrency. If a build or release is queued, it will consume a concurrent pipeline as soon as it can and run to completion.

Comment: I used the custom Capability and custom Demand to limit which agents run my release with UI Tests. Works great. Thank you.